# input zoom on iPhone/Safari not prevented with 16px

Tags: css, iphone, safari

Can someone please help me with this satanic problem...

I read all the guides that the solution is setting the inputs to `16px` but it still doesn't work, and it drives me insane.

```css
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 600px) {
    input {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
```

I don't understand... Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 2):

You can add this code to your html code in the `<head>` tag in html:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`
the `maximum-scale=1` will prevent the zooming of the input and the pages zoom will retain its default zoom level, but the user can still crop the screen to resize if the user wants to.

Comment: This is not a great answer since this will cause issues with accessibility. You should never set the attribute maximum scale to less than 5. https://web.dev/meta-viewport/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=devtools

Answer (score 1):

I tend to typically just specify a few of the most popular input types to set their font size rather than loads, and I wouldn't recommend just targeting `input` since this could affect things like checkboxes too...

```css
input[type="tel"],
input[type="text"],
input[type="date"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="assword"],
textarea {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution #1

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    select,
    select:focus,
    textarea,
    textarea:focus,
    input,
    input:focus {
      font-size: 16px;
    }
}
```

This media query will target only iOS devices

Below is the articles to implement media queries only for targeted devices.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Solution #2

If your website is properly designed for a mobile device you could decide not allow scaling.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need one more attribute:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 600px) {
    input {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me test this out and I'll approve your answer if it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to target the text area, not only the input

```
textarea {
       font-size: 16px;
     }
```

. Also,depending on the input I would use any of these:

```
input[type="color"],
input[type="date"],
input[type="datetime"],
input[type="datetime-local"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="month"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="text"],
input[type="time"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="week"],
select:focus,
 textarea {
   font-size: 16px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply some styles for iPhone, you should detect a touch screen:

```css
@media (hover: none) and (pointer: coarse)
```

so, to set `font-size` on touchscreen for inputs, you should do this:

```css
@media (hover: none) and (pointer: coarse) {
  input[type=text] {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```